# Vercel - Donde puedo monitorear los mensajes del console.log()

Tags: nodejs, vercel

Estoy probando el hosting de VERCEL y se ve muy potente. El tema es que no encuentro los logs como en HEROKU. Es decir, no puedo ver donde chequear por ejemplo las salidas del código siguiente:

```
const cron = require("node-cron"); 
  
const hoy = new Date()

cron.schedule("0 */2 * * * *", () => {

   console.log(hoy);
  
 });
```

La siguiente imagen ilustra el resultado del LOG que provee la documentación  referida en su aporte Andres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según el código compartido, el LOG debería mostrar en la CONSOLA el valor de la variable "hoy".

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier comentario.

Comment: Puedes ver la documentación oficial de vercel aquí -> https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs La búsqueda en google fue: "vercel logs".

Comment: Gracias Andres... fue lo primero que hice cuando instalé Vercel. Pero los registros de ese Log no te muestran el detalle del servidor. En HEROKU, desde la consola de inspección, se podía monitorear las respuestas del console.log(), pero Vercel no tiene eso. O al menos no se donde y ya busqué en la información que me compartiste. De todos modos muchas gracias por tu aporte.